# Wordpress Image Cropper JS Error

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress, upload, crop

I'm getting the following error when attempting to use WP's image cropper to select thumbnail areas.

```
Error: Image corrupt or truncated: http://www.mywordpress.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?
action=imgedit-preview&_ajax_nonce=15ace582fd&postid=749&rand=70651Source File: 
http://www.mywordpress.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=imgedit-preview&
_ajax_nonce=15ace582fdpostid=749&rand=70651
Line: 0
```

I'm uploading with the WP uploader. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old defunct plugin was installed, caused error.